# Merge 2 contiguous elements into 1 using xslt

Tags: xslt

I am new to xslt and am trying different options since few days.
Am kind of out of ideas stuck with below scenario (more because of my lack of knowledge on xslt)

Input xml is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MAIN>
    <ProcessResponse>
        <ORDERNO>workorder123</ORDERNO>
        <NAME>BD-OC 102</NAME>
        <FID>124</FID>
        <FNO>57</FNO>       
        <AID>126</AID>
        <BID>125</BID>

    </ProcessResponse>
    <ProcessResponse>
        <ORDERNO>workorder123</ORDERNO>
        <NAME>BD-OC 102</NAME>
        <FID>125</FID>
        <FNO>58</FNO>
        <AID>127</AID>
        <BID>128</BID>

    </ProcessResponse>
    <ProcessResponse>
        <ORDERNO>workorder124</ORDERNO>
        <NAME>BD-OC 102</NAME>
        <FID>130</FID>
        <FNO>59</FNO>       
        <AID>132</AID>
        <BID>131</BID>

    </ProcessResponse>
    <ProcessResponse>
        <ORDERNO>workorder124</ORDERNO>
        <NAME>BD-OC 102</NAME>
        <FID>132</FID>
        <FNO>60</FNO>
        <AID>133</AID>
        <BID>134</BID>

    </ProcessResponse>

</MAIN>
```

And the output I am expecting is something like (Basically I want every 2 consecutive elements to be merged into 1, merging the part that is not common).
In procedural lang it should e simple but I tried recursive in xslt but did not get desired result.

Output after transformation:

```
<Response>
    <Process>
        <ORDERNO>workorder123</ORDERNO>
        <NAME>BD-OC 102</NAME>

        <F1>
            <FID>124</FID>
            <FNO>57</FNO>       
            <AID>126</AID>
            <BID>125</BID>
        </F1>

        <F2>
            <FID>125</FID>
            <FNO>58</FNO>
            <AID>127</AID>
            <BID>128</BID>
        </F2>

    </Process>

    <Process>
        <ORDERNO>workorder124</ORDERNO>
        <NAME>BD-OC 102</NAME>
        <F1>
            <FID>130</FID>
            <FNO>59</FNO>       
            <AID>132</AID>
            <BID>131</BID>
        </F1>
        <F2>
            <FID>132</FID>
            <FNO>60</FNO>
            <AID>133</AID>
            <BID>134</BID>
        </F2>

    </Process>


</Response>
```

Note: The actual files are much more complex than this but the basic Idea is the same, merge every 2 consecutive blocks into one (the common part).

Any help/Direction/Pointers appreciated.

Comment: Which xslt version? And what is the rule for  merging? Really consecutive, or more because ORDERNO is the same?

Comment: xslt version 1.0
The rule is: Every 2 consecutive (yes because orderno is same) for now the consecutive elements (only 2) will have the same orderno. (Though I guess doing it based on orderno would be more generic) but that would be more than what I am looking for (not that more is a bad thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "merge the 2 consecutive rows" try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kOrderno" match="ProcessResponse" use="ORDERNO" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" >
                <xsl:with-param name="ch" select="h1" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ProcessResponse/ORDERNO"/>
    <xsl:template match="ProcessResponse/NAME"/>
    <xsl:template match="ProcessResponse/text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <Response>
            <xsl:for-each select="ProcessResponse">
                <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
                <Process>
                    <xsl:copy-of  select="ORDERNO"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of  select="NAME"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="on" select="ORDERNO" />
                    <xsl:element name="F1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="F2">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::ProcessResponse[1]/*" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </Process>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Response>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like charm.
The concept I took from your response was "position() mod 2 = 1"
and "following-sibling", dint knew about those, you saved my efforts on weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Try this key based solution [Using Keys to Group: The Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kOrderno" match="ProcessResponse" use="ORDERNO" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" >
                <xsl:with-param name="ch" select="h1" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ProcessResponse/ORDERNO"/>
    <xsl:template match="ProcessResponse/NAME"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <Response>
            <xsl:for-each select="ProcessResponse[count(. | key('kOrderno', ORDERNO)[1] ) =1] ">
                <Process>
                    <xsl:copy-of  select="ORDERNO"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of  select="NAME"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="on" select="ORDERNO" />
                    <xsl:for-each select=" key('kOrderno', $on)" >
                        <xsl:element name="F{position()}">
                            <xsl:apply-templates ></xsl:apply-templates>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Process>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Response>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Response>
  <Process>
    <ORDERNO>workorder123</ORDERNO>
    <NAME>BD-OC 102</NAME>
    <F1>


                <FID>124</FID>
                <FNO>57</FNO>
                <AID>126</AID>
                <BID>125</BID>

        </F1>
    <F2>


                <FID>125</FID>
                <FNO>58</FNO>
                <AID>127</AID>
                <BID>128</BID>

        </F2>
  </Process>
  <Process>
    <ORDERNO>workorder124</ORDERNO>
    <NAME>BD-OC 102</NAME>
    <F1>


                <FID>130</FID>
                <FNO>59</FNO>
                <AID>132</AID>
                <BID>131</BID>

        </F1>
    <F2>


                <FID>132</FID>
                <FNO>60</FNO>
                <AID>133</AID>
                <BID>134</BID>
        </F2>
  </Process>
</Response>
```

Comment: Much appreciated with the answer, I dint even knew there is so much to xslt (I live in the java well, which is deep one by the way).

But, You are relying on orderNo to group the elements, My actual xml is much more complex with around 8 fields which are common (not sharing the xml because it may be propriety). So My best bet is to merge the 2 consecutive rows (the xml I am making is from db rows too as mentioned in 'MUENCHIAN' method.

Comment: Funy, how could I interpret your comment: "*(Though I guess doing it based on orderno would be more generic) but that would be more than what I am looking for (not that more is a bad thing).*" That grouping by orderno could be what you are looking for.  So the orderno is not unique for only two elements?

Comment: yeah my bad, the point here being actual xml has around 8 elements whose combination is unique.
I created above dummy xml to simulate similar condition.
plausible solution I could think was about merging the 2 consecutive (since the query from db which is then transformed to xml always returns only 2 records with few common (orderno, abc, xyz, message, etc).
Sorry for ambiguity in my comments.
And I wanted to upvote your answer, but its not allowing saying I need 15 reps to do that.

Your answer is awesome, but currently does not work for me.